# Bluetooth crashing after turning on a certain device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing an app that involves Bluetooth low energy scanning and am facing a strange error. BLE scanning works fine for most devices, but as soon as I turn on a certain temperature sensor within range, bluetooth will crash on my device (Kindle Fire) and turn off. Scanning then stops working entirely until I can turn bluetooth back on. The temperature sensor does not show in the ListView that scanned devices are added to so I'm not sure if a ScanCallback is even occuring for the sensor before the crash. Does anyone know possible causes of this problem?

Here is my ScanLeDevice() method and ScanCallback:

```
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        scanning = true;
        scanner.startScan(filterList, settings, mLeScanCallback);
        scanPost();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Stop scanning after 10 seconds
                scanLeDevice(false);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
    } else {
        scanning = false;
        scanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
//            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        this.stopScan();
    }
}



private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                final int new_rssi = result.getRssi();
                final BluetoothDevice new_device = result.getDevice();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // add to view
                        //TODO: add in check in UUIDs to make sure only temperature sensors are added

                        if (new_rssi > -90) {
                            adapter.addDevice(new_device, new_rssi);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Here are the logcat findings:

```
E/BTLD:##################################################################
E/BTLD: #
E/BTLD: # WARNING : BTU HCI(id=0) command timeout. opcode=0x2006
E/BTLD: #
E/BTLD:##################################################################
E/bt-hci: Num consecutive HCI Cmd tout =2 Restarting BT process
E/bt-btm: cannot interpret APCF callback status = 0, length = 1
E/BTLD: ##################################################################
E/BTLD: #
E/BTLD: # WARNING : BTU HCI(id=0) command timeout. opcode=0x2006
E/BTLD: #
E/BTLD: ##################################################################
E/bt-hci: Num consecutive HCI Cmd tout =2 Restarting BT process
E/BT_UTILS: bt_utils_set_pts_flag, pts_enable 0
E/bt_osi_config: config_new unable to open file '/etc/bluetooth/ble_stack.conf': No such file or directory
E/BT_UTILS: bt_utils_set_pts_flag, pts_enable 0
E/bt_osi_config: config_new unable to open file '/etc/bluetooth/ble_stack.conf': No such file or directory
E/[BT]: init_uart: Can't open serial port
E/bt_userial: userial_open unable to open serial port.
E/bt_userial: userial_write error writing to serial port: Bad file number 9
E/bt-btif: ...preload_wait_timeout (retried:0/max-retry:0)...
E/[BT]: thread_exit: pthread_mutex_unlock error
E/WifiStateMachine: sending event=NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, info=[state: CONNECTING/OBTAINING_IPADDR, reason: null, isAvailable: true]
E/BT_UTILS: bt_utils_set_pts_flag, pts_enable 0
E/bt_osi_config: config_new unable to open file 
'/etc/bluetooth/ble_stack.conf': No such file or directory
E/bt-btm: BTM_SecRegister:p_cb_info->p_le_callback == 0xa3943529 
E/bt-btm: BTM_SecRegister: btm_cb.api.p_le_callback = 0xa3943529 
E/bt-btif: Calling BTA_HhEnable
E/bt-btif: btif_storage_get_adapter_property service_mask:0x2100028
E/bt-btif: btif_hf_upstreams_evt: Invalid index 8223
E/bt_h4: vendor lib postload completed
```

Comment: What Android OS version is your Kindle Fire running?

Comment: Please show us some code and explain what's your specific doubt.

Comment: How sad. Report the issue to the manufacturer of the kindle

Comment: @Emil The same problem is happening on a second kindle, so I dont think it's a problem with the bluetooth hardware of the specific kindle it that's what you were implying

Comment: @tomacco It's running Fire OS 5.4.0.0

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt I will add my ScanLeDevice() method and ScanCallback in an edit to my post. Let me know if there's anything else you think is important to add

Comment: If the bluetooth service of an Android device crashes just because it detects a nearby device then it's definitely a bug in the software of the Android device.

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt I did some debugging and the ScanCallback is almost never called before the crash, so code in it can't be the source of the problem

Comment: @eagren what exception is shown on your logcat?

Comment: why don't you post the crash logcat......

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt The app itself isn't crashing so there isn't an exception in logcat, but I added the weird things that I found to the main post

Comment: @GuoXingmin above

Comment: And you aren't finding anything more relating to Bluetooth in the logcat output of you remove all log filtering?

Comment: @Emil I removed all filtering and I might have found something. Added it to the main post

Comment: Well that doesn't look good at all. The Bluetooth controller doesn't reply anymore so it resets it. Maybe you could find out more if you look at the hci snoop log?

Comment: @Emil Ok I'll get the log file when I can and get back to you

Comment: @Emil Do you know how to read the file? I copied the log file to my computer but I don't know how to read it

Comment: You open it in Wireshark

Comment: @Emil Thank you, I've successfully opened it in wireshark, but I have no idea how to interpret the information. There isn't anything that says error if that's what I should be looking for

Comment: Hmm maybe it isn't that easy in the case it gets cleaned upon every restart. Is it kind of a small file after the issue occurs? You can also look at the time stamps in the log to figure out how old the first entry is.

Comment: @Emil in the most recent file there are 124 frames of information (6 KB). Also, something that's unrelated but might be worth mentioning is that manually clearing the cache in the app settings lets the app get several callbacks successfully from the peripheral before bluetooth stops working